# How to add wireless capability to DC Electric Charging Vehicle Diagram?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am using this DC EV Charger model as a base for research provided by Mathworks:
https://www.mathworks.com/help/sps/ug/dc-fast-charger.html

I want to add some wireless receiver/transciever to the diagram so I can better simulate what I want for my research. I've done some digging and found this model also provided by Mathworks: https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/wireless-transceiver-design-and-network-modeling-in-simulink.html

I want to have help on how to merge these two models together so that I can have a EV DC Model with wireless/IoT capability.